# Can Karthus' Ult Hit Fizz During Playful Trickster?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that Fizz is untargetable during playful trickster, but can Karthus' ult still hit him?

Comment: No. If Fizz times it correctly, he'll avoid the damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you time your <kbd>E</kbd>(Playful Trickster) correctly you can avoid Karthus Ultimate.

Helpful Forum Link [here](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=17342736)

Answer (score 1):

No. While Fizz is using Playful/Trickster he become untargetable. Karthus' ultimate won't hit.

Comment: Much confusion comes from using this reasoning. Karthus's ult is a channeled spell. At the end of that channeled spell, damage is done that can be avoided with Fizz's E. Conversely: Fiddlesticks's drain is a channeled spell whose damage cannot be avoided by Fizz's E, and Vladimir's ult is a debuff that does burst damage at the end of a short timer whose damage cannot be avoided by Fizz's E.

Comment: That is because fiddle and Vladimir target at the start of the spell. Karthus channels and then targets at end.